# Material Design Theme Error

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I've recently decided to start using "material design" in my application.  Getting this error during compile:

```
Error:(12, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.
```

Below it's pointing to this styles.xml

```
<resources>
<!--
      Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
      by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
  -->
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You should probably use  `android:windowNoTitle`.

Comment: Why not use `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`? It does this for you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change `<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>` to `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>`.

Only some attributes, mostly related to the `appcompat-v7` library, need the `android:`-less version. For all the others, you should always use the android prefix.

Comment: Thanks. I literally spent 2 hours updating libraries and trying to figure this out.